# Access value of read input from within a function in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm have a function wrapper for `read` command. I'm trying to automate most of input asking in my script by a function. Below is *non*-working code.

```bash
ask_input() {
  _question="$1"
  _thevar="$2"
  _finalvar=$(eval $(echo $_thevar))
  read -ep "${_question}: " "$_thevar"
  printf "%s\n" "$_question" "$_thevar" "$_finalvar"
}
```

Basically what I'm hoping is when I execute following.

```bash
ask_input "Do you like apple (yes/no)" the_answer
```

If an user type `yes`, each variable will contain following (w/o quotes of course, it was just for easier readability).

```
$_question --> "Do you like apple (yes/no)"
$_thevar --> "the_answer"
$_finalvar --> "yes"
```

The `eval` command is my attempt to solve the problem, but I have not found the actual solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main two things you need to change are: 1) use indirect expansion with `!` (`_finalvar="${!_thevar}"`) instead of messing with `eval`, and do that *after* reading something into that variable. I'd also recommend making all those variables local to the function. So something like this:

```
ask_input() {
    local _question="$1"
    local _thevar="$2"
    read -ep "${_question}: " "$_thevar"
    local _finalvar="${!_thevar}" 
    printf "%s\n" "$_question" "$_thevar" "$_finalvar"
}
```

Since those variables are local now, you could probably also remove the `_` prefixes (unless you're worried about a conflict with the variable name supplied as `$2`).

Comment: Thanks, just for completeness-- can you add a POSIX compliant alternative ?

Comment: You could use `eval _finalvar=\$${_thevar}` for POSIX compliance, but there are several other changes needed: the `-ep` options to `read` are both bashisms, and you'd have to remove the `local` declarations I recommended. BTW, there's more discussion of this in [BashFAQ #6: "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: Yes, the script actually was written under dash, but I gave up and switch to bash because I need `read` that support readline and able to backspace without giving `^H ^H` in prompt.